# Install HTMX Into A New Laravel Project Via NPM

Tags: laravel, htmx

I have installed HTMX into my new Laravel 10 project via NPM, but can't figure out why it won't work? Do I need to add the following lines to my bootstrap.js file, like so:

```
import 'htmx.org';
window.htmx = require('htmx.org');
```

Then run npm run dev? I have tried running some small animations from the HTMX documentation, but they don't work?

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is a bug that doesn't allow htmx to work properly with Vite:

https://github.com/bigskysoftware/htmx/issues/1469

As a workaround, I am using htmx at the bottom of the body, and adding any script related to htmx there:

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/htmx.org@1.9.3"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/htmx.org/dist/ext/ajax-header.js"></script>

<script>
    document.body.addEventListener('htmx:configRequest', function (event) {
        event.detail.headers['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').content;
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

As David mentioned, you can add scripts directly from cdn.

You can see an example [TODO app here](https://github.com/icaliman/laravel-htmx).

I am working on a Laravel module named **[lamx](https://github.com/xlited/lamx)** that provides functionality to easily incorporate HTMX into Laravel applications.